Meaning/Definition of Smoothing
I am self-studying Vector Generalized Linear/Additive Models (mostly) via Yee, T. W. (2015) "Vector Generalized Linear and Additive Models: With an Implementation in R."
This book has many discussions of smoothing. As far as I can tell, this always means fitting data via some kind of regression with smooth functions and/or doing a penalized fit (where the penalty forces a smoother result).
Based on online references (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing) it appears that smoothing can refer to either a fit like those described above or a procedure that modifies the data directly to vary more smoothly (e.g. averaging a data point with its neighbors or something of that nature).
So, for the purposes of reading Yee I am mentally substituting "smoothing" with "smooth fitting" and more generally my understanding is the "smoothing" refers to any procedure which produces a smoother representation of some data (whether it is a curve or just smoother data).
Is this concept formally defined? If not, is there any error in my thinking?

I don't understand the difference between the two things you contrast in your paragraph starting "based on".  The fits do change the data, in essence.

This could be what I'm missing... why would a fit change the data? It seems like you can produce a fitted curve (something not in the form of the original data) or you can produce a new dataset. I.e. do $x_{k}'=.25x_{k-1}+.5x_{k}+.25*x_{k+1}$ or something like that.

Maybe there is a difference, but it seems more technical or philosophical. None of the methods actually change the data, they just make a fit on adjusted data.  But maybe I am just confused.

I guess this is a way to make the distinction more concrete. In the latter case, I'd expected the data to be (1) smoothed and then (2) fit -- because after step 1 it still looks like data. In the second, the smooth fit is the fit... so smoothing and fitting are one step. No?

Some smoothers reduce variation but aren't especially smooth in any informal sense. Running medians are an easy example, as a running median can leave in its wake jumps and flat stretches. Velleman's 4253H smoother is an example that tries to reduce those effects; it is (1) take medians of 4s (2) take medians of 2s (3) take medians of 5s (4) take medians of 3s (5) apply Hanning, i.e. means in a window of 3 with weights (1 2 1) / 4. Steps (1) (2)  often involve some averaging and (5) does too.
